# Django stuck on default page

Tags: python, django, webserver

I have django set up on a server, but it will only return the default "Welcome to Django" page.

I also have django set up on a local machine, and I use git to push the files to the server.

Both the server and local machine are configured with apache/wsgi.

On the local machine it will display the webapp as intended, but on deployment to the server, it shows nothing but the default page.

Restarting apache on the server and even an error in the django project have not made a difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try running the dev server on another port and see if that works.  `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080` or whatever port you want and see if that works.

Comment: Also worth noting, The server is a mac, while my local machine is Windows

Comment: @TNels: Both bad choices, but unlikely to be a problem once you got this far.

Comment: The server isn't mac by my choice, and I've been seriously debating installing Debian to another hard drive and using that to work on this project. Windows is a pain to configure django apps/plugins for.

Answer (score 2):

i am assuming you have django set up locally. if that is so, then you are using localhost. it is suppose to show the welcome page unless you configure on the url.py to redirect it to somewhere else. it would be useful if you showed us the url.py. if the welcome page or the url.py has not been altered, then i dont know what else it would change to besides the default welcome page.

Comment: It works perfect locally(urls.py has been configured), it returns my webapp and such. The problem occurs when I try and access the url for the server and it only shows the default page.

Comment: @TNels: There can be an infinite amount of reason for that, from you not actually putting your development code up on the server to Apache being incorrectly configured. It's impossible to answer without actually debugging the problem.

Comment: I have been debugging the problem: Apache is configured correctly, and the code is there.

Comment: @TNels: Did you try running the development server to see if that is working on your server?